# Python Paramiko download multiple files to window client over SSH

Tags: python

I would like to download multiple files under linux server to my window clients, i have many files under desktop

test_file1_20200601_0001.csv
test_file1_20200601_0002.csv
test_file1_20200601_0003.csv
test_file1_20200601_0004.csv
test_file1_20200601_0004.csv
.
.
test_file1_20200601_0400.csv

**Here is my code**

```
dt_today  = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(0), '%Y%m%d')
dt_yesday = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y%m%d')

Destination = os.path.join(os.sep,str(Path.home()),'Template and Raw','Raw')
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('192.168.1.1', username="server1", password="server1@123")
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

for filename in sftp.listdir('/home/server1/Desktop/test/'+ dt_yesday):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, 'test_file1_'+dt_yesday+'*.csv'):
        sftp.get(filename, Destination)
sftp.close()
```

**And i got this Error**

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\YouKnowWho\Template and Raw\Raw'

**May i know how can i fix this**

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko source shows that the get method opens `localpath` for writing.
You're passing a folder to `.get`.

```
    def get(self, remotepath, localpath, callback=None):
        """
        Copy a remote file (``remotepath``) from the SFTP server to the local
        host as ``localpath``.  Any exception raised by operations will be
        passed through.  This method is primarily provided as a convenience.

        :param str remotepath: the remote file to copy
        :param str localpath: the destination path on the local host
        :param callable callback:
            optional callback function (form: ``func(int, int)``) that accepts
            the bytes transferred so far and the total bytes to be transferred

        .. versionadded:: 1.4
        .. versionchanged:: 1.7.4
            Added the ``callback`` param
        """
        with open(localpath, "wb") as fl:
            size = self.getfo(remotepath, fl, callback)
        s = os.stat(localpath)
        if s.st_size != size:
            raise IOError(
                "size mismatch in get!  {} != {}".format(s.st_size, size)
            )
```

Comment: Its not work, still showing file permission error in window.